# Pass Button that Triggered ContextMenu

Tags: android

So I am new to android programming and learning as I go. I am currently developing a soundboard that allows users to set a sound as a ringtone or notification. I have gotten the context menu set up successfully and I am able to differentiate between what the user clicks within the contextmenu. My only problem is I can't figure out how to tell which button triggered the contextmenu. Can anybody help?

Thanks
Justin

Edit: I was able to find a solution. Here is how I did it:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        lastButton = (Button) v;
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Ringtone:
                if(lastButton == SoundButton)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ringtone soundbutton selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.Notification:
                if(lastButton == SoundButtonButton){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notification soundbutton set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to set an `id` for the view before you register your context menu.  If you're using a button:

```
    Button button = ...;
    button.setId(some_id);

    Button button2 = ...;
    button2.setId(some_id_2);
    ...

    registerForContextMenu(b);  

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == some_id)
            ...
        else if (id == some_id_2)
            ...
    }
```

Comment: setting the button id causes my layout to mess up. A few buttons are on top of each other. And using the button id's that are declared in the layout.xml does not work either.